# Time complexity for operations in implementation of Stack and Queue

Tags: arrays, list, stack, queue

I am studying about data structures and have some doubts about time complexity in different implementations of stacks and queues.

For queues, were an element can be queued at the head or at the tail, a dynamic array implementation gives O(1) amortized time for insertion at end and beginning. A linked list implementation gives a O(1) implementation.

For stacks, were a node can be added at the beginning or at the end of the list, a singly linked list and an array implementation will both give a O(1) time complexity.

Am I right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain index on the next insertion location then the Insertion operation will take a constant amount of time so O(1) is correct.

But if no indexes are maintained then we need to search for the correct location to insert the new element and the time it takes to insert this element will linearly increase with number of elements in the data structure, so the insertion time in this case would be O(n)